# Looking for not/continuous and differentiable function examples?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

I have to give an example of functions which are:

**continuous and not differentiable**

$f(x)=|x|$

**differentiable**

$f(x)=(1/2)* x *|x|$

**not continuous**

$f(x)=1/x$ and $f(x)=1/cos(x) [0;\pi]$

Are these examples correct?

Comment: $x*|x|$... you mean $x^2?$

Comment: I don't understand what you want for the third one. You want a continuous function which is not continuous?

Comment: @CalvinLin: Shouldn't the OP indicate the set to clarify continuous on what or differentiable on which?

Comment: differentiable equation tag? ;-)

Comment: ok, I corrected my mistakes. The question is to give these 3 types of functions and I would like to aks you if they are correct or not?

Comment: @maximus I think you mean "Give an example of functions that are :"

Comment: @CalvinLin thx for your answer!!! yes, this is what I mean!!! btw did I said sth. else;)

Comment: Linear-algebra??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell whether your examples are correct or not, as you haven't specified the function domains in most cases.

- $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous and differentiable on $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$, but non-differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $f(x) = \frac{x|x|}2$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous on $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. We cannot speak of its continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ because it is not defined on the whole real line.

The only function that you have tried to specify a domain is $f(x)=1/\cos(x)$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$. Yet this is not a well posed example because $f$ is undefined at $x=\pi/2$. Yet you can turn it into a valid example by defining the missing value. For instance, define $f:[0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1/\cos(x)$ if $x\not=\pi/2$ and $f(\pi/2)=0$. Then $f$ is discontinuous at $x=\pi/2$.